# Cursor not being updated after FragmentManager.popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I have my implementation of `ListFragment` which uses my implementation of `CursorAdapter` and implements `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. When the user taps on one of the item in this list, the user is taken to a different `fragment`. Here the user has an option to **delete** the particular item that was clicked on.

Now in the `deleteFooItem()` I use a my implementation of `ContentProvider` which does the delete. This is as below:

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = sqlitehelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TJItemTable.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsDeleted;
}
```

This arrangement works fine.

But after the delete happens, I call `fragmentManager.popBackStack()` to go back to the original `ListFragment`. Here the list still shows old data that I just deleted. Upon debugging, the `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)` does get called, but this swaps the cursor with a cursor that still has the old information.

If I close the app and open it again, then the list does not show the deleted information.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure your ``onCreateLoader``' s uri is the same as the ``delete``' s uri on that fragment.

Comment: No, my second fragment has its own `LoaderManger` and its own `onCreate(), onLoadFinished()` etc. So what do I do in this case? How do I contact my previous `LoaderManager`.

Comment: However, the delete on the `ContentProvider` is called with the correct URI.

Comment: Just execute your loader again.  The onStart() or onResume() methods should work if your already using a LoaderManger.LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    lm.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);

It might be clunky as it would put the list back to the top.

Comment: What I did was in the ParentActivity, I keep a flag of the item deleted. And in the bindview, I first check if the item is deleted or not. If yes, then I don't bind that view. This is working fine, but I am not sure if it is the right way. Not sure what do you mean by 'Just execute your loader again'. Yes, I am using the loader manager as you said.